# Enter in to a particular page through the browser after I login to the system

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, spring-security, struts

Need some idea on the process to land in a page after I login to my web portal. My requirement is I will enter Url of a particular page in to the browser, then system will check is the user is login to the system, if yes it will land on the page I have entered but if not then system will take me to the login page and after successful login I will be landed in to the page I have entered in the browser.

So, please tell me how to do it in plain servlet/Jsp model, Spring and Struts 1 and Struts 2.

Any post will be helpful

Comment: http://andrealigios.blogspot.it/2012/08/struts2-write-your-own-interceptor-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know about basic jsp/servlet model.

Write a Servlet filter which will intercept every request from the brwoser, there check is the user is logged in or not. If logged in your normal flow will continue but if not then redirect to the login page. When you are redirecting to the login page, make sure you send the url hit by browser in the response. Now in client side hold the url send in response and after eneter credentials in login page when user will submit the record send the url (Hold in the client side from response)  in the request and after successful login use Servelet Request dispatcher to land in the url.

I am not sure but spring-security has this feature and struts 2. But implementation process can be share by others who are familiar on this technologies. But in struts 1 it's not available and you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

it will very easy with spring security you just need to secure some path pattern. you doesn't need to add some code in your jsp or controller, example

```
for url /admin/* need administrator role
for url /user/* need user role
for url /public/* no need login (anynomous)
```

it just need configure at your spring-security.xml

you can start [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html)